# Need the complete formula in one cell

Tags: worksheet-function

I need the complete formula in one cell.

100000 is in Column A, Row 1

100000 * 0.15%  = 150
150 * 13%       = 19.5
100000 * 0.25%  = 250
19.5 + 250      = 269.5

I need result 269.5 in Column B, Row 1

Comment: result be 419.5

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=A1 * 0.15% * 13% + A1 * 0.25%
```

[image]